# Grunt not using right JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, gruntjs

I am trying with Grunt to read environment specific JSON file. But it is always reading from the default.json file. Am I missing something?

Here is my code snippet for `Gruntfile.js`

```
var config = require('config');
var host = config.get('host');
console.log(host);
```

Here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "grunt",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Test app",
  "main": "grunt.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Me,
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-nodeunit": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.5.0",
    "load-grunt-config": "^0.17.2",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.2.0"
  }
}
```

I have

`host=localhost` in `default.json` and

`host=someURL` in `production.json`

Commands I am running in command line

```
$ set NODE_ENV="production"
$ grunt
  localhost
  Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

  Aborted due to warnings.
```

Comment: Is config a JSON file?  If you are trying to pull it in from the current directory, you need to specify a relative path:  require('./config').  Otherwise with the way you have it, the require will look in node_modules for it.

Comment: No ... `config` is from http://lorenwest.github.io/node-config/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work. I was using `SET` instead of `export` for setting `NODE_ENV`.

```
$ export NODE_ENV=production
```